# How do I iterate over an array of objects match a common element from another array and return the key value for "name"

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I would like to map over an array of objects. If the `id` of each object matches the `id` from another array then I want to return the movie name.

I have seen other threads about this and have used `.map` and `.find` however for some reason my code does not return the result I want.

[Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

```
const moviesNamesAndGenres = [
   {id: 28, name: "Action"},
   {id: 12, name: "Adventure"},
   {id: 14, name: "Animation"}
]

const genreIds = [14, 28, 13];


const test = genreIds.map((genreId) => {
      const matchedGenres = moviesNamesAndGenres.find((movieObj) => {
         return movieObj.id === genreId
      })
      return matchedGenres // this returns the matching objects, cool
})
```

At this point I have the following as two objects in the array for ids that matched.

```
{ id: 14, name: 'Animation' }
{ id: 28, name: 'Action' }
undefined
```

I would now like to return the `name` for each object

here is my code attempt:

```
const result = test.map((el) => {
  return el.name
})

console.log(result)
```

Now I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

could someone help me understand why?

Comment: `13` is not in `moviesNamesAndGenres` so one of `test` variable values would be `undefined`, as you printed. so in your `test.map`, accessing `name` property of `undefined` would throw an error.
You should not use map, and use something else like `reduce`, or you can filter `undefined` values before you run the last `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `filter` out elements for which no matching object was found.

```js
const moviesNamesAndGenres = [
   {id: 28, name: "Action"},
   {id: 12, name: "Adventure"},
   {id: 14, name: "Animation"}
]

const genreIds = [14, 28, 13];


const test = genreIds.map((genreId) => {
      const matchedGenres = moviesNamesAndGenres.find((movieObj) => {
         return movieObj.id === genreId
      })
      return matchedGenres // this returns the matching objects, cool
})
const result = test.filter(Boolean).map((el) => {
  return el.name
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks for the code. So does `test.filter(Boolean)` filter out the elements in the array that are not true I'm guessing? I never knew that. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is what it does.

Comment: Hello iota sorry. Let me try again I added it but it didnt work. Its probably something I am doing. It looks like what i want though as i console logged everything. I will accept shortly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. You are trying to access a property of an undefined object. There is no match between the object with id:14 and the number 13 of the Array.

Comment: wasn't clear to me that's why i asked "upside down smiley face" :S

Comment: And that's why i tried to help you...i only trying to say that the console shows the error very clear

Comment: ok thanks, sorry to snap I was just quite frustrated at the time, thanks for your help @Belgica

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.map` over the array `genreIds`, extract the name, and finally filter out the undefined values (those not found objects).

```js
const moviesNamesAndGenres = [   {id: 28, name: "Action"},   {id: 12, name: "Adventure"},   {id: 14, name: "Animation"}],
      genreIds = [14, 28, 13],
      result = genreIds.map(g => (moviesNamesAndGenres.find(m => m.id === g) || {}).name).filter(Boolean);
        
console.log(result);
```